# Ansible apt module showing "item changed" when I don't think it did

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to install Apache2 with Ansible. I have a role and handler for Apache.

My playbook (`site.yml`) contains:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: ansrun
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
```

The Ansible role file contains:

```
---
- name: Install Apache 2
  apt: name={{ item }} update_cache=yes state=present
  with_items:
    - apache2
  when: ansible_distribution == "Ubuntu"

- name: Enable mod_rewrite
  apache2_module: name=rewrite state=present
  notify:
    - reload apache2
```

Whenever I run the playbook, I get this message, but nothing has changed.

```
changed: [10.0.1.200] => (item=[u'apache2'])
```

I think this has something to do with the conditional.

Comment: Can you post the entire output? Also add this to your play. `- debug: var=ansible_distribution`

Answer (score 2):

You are running into a [problem](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/5484) introduced to Ansible 2.2.0 (and fixed in 2.2.1).

With `update_cache=yes` the `apt` module was made to return `changed`-status whenever APT cache update occurred, not only when the actual package was upgraded.

You need to upgrade Ansible to version 2.2.1 (released officially on Jan 16th)

<strike>You need to do one of the following:</strike>

- upgrade Ansible to at least 2.2.1 (currently in release candidate state and not available in PyPI, so you'd have to [run Ansible from source](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#running-from-source));
- downgrade Ansible to 2.1.3;
- retain Ansible 2.2.0 and split the `Install Apache 2` task into two:

  - one for cache update only (maybe with `changed_when` set to `false`),
  - one for the actual `apache2` package installation (without `update_cache=yes`), calling the handler.